# AngularJS iterate over $dirty elements

Tags: angularjs

I already know how to check if certain input elements on my form are dirty or not, but I was wondering if there was a quick way to just iterate over just the $dirty ones only?  I know Angular sets a ng-dirty class on the elements, and I can figure out how to do this in jQuery, but I can't figure out how to do it in AngularJS context.

Comment: Are you looking for something like a filter?

Comment: So, you can do this by grabbing an instance of NgFormController in your custom directive. BUT, the real question is _why_ you would like to iterate over such elements? What is your functional use-case?

Comment: A large form is pre-populated with data. I'd like to just send the updated fields out through $http POST.

Comment: That is exactly what I use the dirty filter for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wrote a filter (with some help from the community) to do that a while back and it has served me pretty well.

```
/* App Module */
angular.module("dirtyFilter", []).
filter("returnDirtyItems", function () {        
return function (modelToFilter, form, treatAsDirty, removeTheseCharacters) {
    //removes pristine items
    //note: treatAsDirty must be an array containing the names of items that should not be removed
    for (var key in modelToFilter) {
        //delete the item if:
        //    * it exists on the form and is pristine, or...
        //    * does not exist on the form
        try{
            //console.log("checking " + key + " for pristine and found it is " + form[key].$pristine);
        }
        catch(err){
            //console.log("key " + key + " did not have an element in the form");
        }
        if (removeTheseCharacters != undefined && removeTheseCharacters.length > 0) {
            for (var CA = 0, len = removeTheseCharacters.length; CA < len; CA++ ) {
                try{
                    //console.log("Index of " + key + " is: " + modelToFilter[key].indexOf(removeTheseCharacters[CA]));
                    if (modelToFilter[key].indexOf(removeTheseCharacters[CA]) >= 0) {
                        modelToFilter[key] = modelToFilter[key].replace(removeTheseCharacters[CA], "", "g");
                    }
                }
                catch(err){
                    //console.log("getting the index of " + key + " throws an error of " + err + " so we skipped it");
                }
            }
        }
        if ((form[key] && form[key].$pristine) || !form[key]) {
            //delete the item if the treatAsDirty argument is not present
            //console.log("Checking to see if " + key + " is to be treated as always dirty");
            if(treatAsDirty){
                //console.log("There is an array present for treatAsDirty");
                //delete the item if it is not in the treatAsDirty array
                if(treatAsDirty.indexOf(key) == -1){
                    //console.log("The item " + key + " was not found in the always dirty array and has been deleted");
                    //remove the pristine item from the parent object
                    delete modelToFilter[key];
                } else {
                    //console.log("The item " + key + " was found in the always dirty array and has been kept");
                }
            } else {
                //console.log("There is no array present for dirty items, so " + key + " will be removed");
                //remove the pristine item from the parent object
                delete modelToFilter[key];
            }
        }
    }
    return modelToFilter;
}
});
```

You can see it in action at http://jsfiddle.net/mbielski/sdN2h/1/